# Making a dashboard that shows list of ip's with latency

Tags: php, html, formatting, ping, dashboard

I am trying to make a page in PHP and HTML that pings a list of IP's in a file called `ips.txt` and returns it to a nic HTML / PHP page where I show said data in the following format

```
IP - Latency
```

And I have no clue how I would tackle this issue. I could ping every IP but how would I show that data? And how would I format it? I could use `exec()` But I have no clue. If anyone knows any smart way to do it and could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For good start

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<ol>
<?php
    $lists =['1.1.1.1', '8.8.8.8','8.8.8.4','080'];
    $output=null;
    $retval=null;
    
    foreach($lists as $ip)
    {   
        $output=null;
        $retval=null;
        exec('ping  '.$ip.' -n 1 -w 100', $output, $retval);
        if($output[0] != '')
           echo '<li>'.$ip.' = '.$output[0].'</li>';
        else
           echo '<li>'.$ip.' = '.$output[5].'</li>';
    }
    
?>
</ol>
<body>
</html>
```

This output this

```
   1) 1.1.1.1 = Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
   2) 8.8.8.8 = Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
   3) 8.8.8.4 = Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
   4) 080 = Ping request could not find host 080. Please check the name and try again.
```

Comment: And if we wanted to use a list we would use `foreach()` right? And how would we get this to a frontend?

Comment: there are many ways - the list of addresses can be in a .txt file, you have to load it and read it in a loop. If you ask how to pass data from php to html - something tells me that you do not know what you are doing

Comment: I mean that if i am done with the ping how would I get the result of a 100 plus IP's back to a nice frontend?

Comment: If the IP is dynamically supplied by user input, ensure you [escape the input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) to prevent from RCE.